# Unity iOS Plugin for Bluetooth communication - Swift or Objective-C

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine, plugins, bluetooth

I want to create a native iOS plugin for Unity to enable an iPhone app to communicate over Bluetooth and use Unity to display the received data.

From my current point of view I see two ways:

- Create a Swift library: Preferred as I already have knowledge in Swift, but as it seems I would have to create Objective-C bridge classes to be able to access the Swift methods in Unity.
- Learn Objective-C and create an Objective-C library

As it seems Objective-C is required anyway but using Apple's recommended programming language Swift would be a more recent approach.

Which way would currently be best-practice?

Answer (score 1):

Unity only knows Objective-C. Therefore you would need to write in Objective-C or write in Swift and have some kind of bridge, as you mentioned.

As Bluetooth has a lot of boilerplate code and some level of complexity and swift is much nicer *and you know it already*, I would try the bridge-approach first. The Bridge-API will be easy and not change much over time.

There are some projects like [unity-swift](https://github.com/miyabi/unity-swift) that can help you to get started.

You will know very fast if this is an approach that fits you, even before you start with the Bluetooth stuff.